# A probability problem, Maximum likelihood or Bayesian updating?

Tags: probability

I see an interesting probability problem:

> Suppose you were playing table tennis with A, you did not know the
>   strength of A. Since the start, A had won 3 scores consecutively. What
>   was the probability that A won the 4th game?

My first thought is that to assume a probability distribution of winning a game for A, and based on that, use conditional probability and Bayesian updating to solve the problem.

However, one of my friend proposed that this problem seemed just like the definition for Maximum likelihood...

Can anyone give me some hint on how you think about this question?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Bayesian approach is generally to be preferred as it will give you more information. In order to do that, it is necessary to *make assumptions*. One reasonable and simple assumption set could be the following:

1. The *a-priori* probability $p \in [0,1]$ of A winning a single game (before playing any game with A) is distributed as $f(p)=1, \; p \in [0,1]$.
2. The outcome of a single game is independent of the outcome of other games.

We will use $\mathcal{H}$ to denote the above set of assumptions. Note that we considered the (non-informative) uniform *a-priori* pdf for $p$, since, given the information we have prior to playing a single game, we have no reason to believe that A is "good" or "bad" player. Note also that this non-informative *a-priori* pdf gives the reasonable probability of A winning equal to 1/2. Indeed,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\textrm{A wins a game}|\mathcal{H}) &= \int_0^1\mathbb{P}(\textrm{A wins a game}|p)f(p|\mathcal{H})dp\\
&=\int_0^1p1 dp\\
&=1/2,
\end{align}
where we used the notation $f(p|\mathcal{H})$ as a reminder that the considered *a-priori* pdf corresponds to the particular assumption $\mathcal{H}$. The above can be viewed as the *a-priori* probability of A winning a game (given $\mathcal{H}$).

Now, let $\mathcal{D}\triangleq\{\textrm{A won the first 3 games}\}$. Given $\mathcal{D}$ (and $\mathcal{H}$), we can update our belief on the skill of A as reflected by the *a-posteriori* pdf of $p$. This can be computed as

\begin{align}
f(p|\mathcal{D},\mathcal{H})&=\frac{f(\mathcal{D}|p,\mathcal{H})f(p|\mathcal{H})}{f(\mathcal{D}|\mathcal{H})}\\
&=\frac{p^31}{\int_0^1p^3 1 dp}\\
&=4p^3.
\end{align}

The *a-priori* and *a-posteriori* pdf of $p$ are shown in the following figure. Note that the *a-posteriori* pdf is tilted towards $p=1$, i.e., A is more probable to be a good player ($p$ is large).

[image]

Note that the *a-posteriori* pdf is much more informative on the skill of A than an estimate of the probability of A winning the 4-th game (as provided by, e.g., a maximum likelihood approach). In fact, the bayesian approach can provide the probability of A winning the 4-th game as
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\textrm{A wins a game}|\mathcal{D},\mathcal{H}) &= \int_0^1\mathbb{P}(\textrm{A wins a game}|p)f(p|\mathcal{D},\mathcal{H})dp\\
&=\int_0^1p4p^3 dp\\
&=4/5,
\end{align}
i.e., given the observation $\mathcal{D}$ we now believe that the probability of A winning a game is 0.8 instead of 0.5 we believed before playing any game.

If you have reasons to consider another hypothesis, say $\mathcal{H}'$, you would follow the same approach. Furthermore, you could also consider combining both hypothesis by specifying probabilities for the assumption sets $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{H})=1-\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{H'})$ (and similarly if you want to consider more possible assumptions). It is impossible to do the latter with a maximum likelihood approach, i.e., you need to devise heuristic approaches if a maximum likelihood approach is to be considered when many assumptions/models are plausible.